# Should canonical tags be used on two related pages about the same subject

Tags: seo, canonical-url

If I have a page which is related to a product category, and it has two subdirs with different type of content, do I need to use a canonical to the 'main page'?

For example:

```
example.com/watches/ 
example.com/watches/sell/ 
example.com/watches/buy/
```

In this case the main page is the first one, it lists all of the products ordered by the date they were published. However some users want to buy only or sell only, therefore it's better to give them the option to choose.

Since buying and selling are two different (but related) things, I would say the canonical is not needed, because if people search for watches to buy, they are not interested in selling watches.

Or I should forget the `example.com/watches/` and only keep the two different pages for the two different user groups?

I would really appreciate if somebody could tell me what would be the best in this situation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way you have it now is fine, no need to make one canonical over the others. In this case, you have three different pages, and all these pages are serving a different purpose. I would keep the aggregate page (example.com/watches/) too, because there's no reason to take away a page that a watch lover can explore and see everything watch-related your site has to offer.

You will need to use canonicals when you get down to individual watch listings. For example, say you have a certain watch that can be reached via the category page and also the buy page:

example.com/watches/this-watch

example.com/watches/buy/this-watch

Here, you will have to choose one of these URL's and bestow a canonical tag on it. Which one you choose is up to you, based on your site structure and other factors, but make sure it's only one.

Comment: One watch has one link, no pages like `example.com/watches/this-watch`. Products are not duplicated on the two type of pages, the product url's like `example.com/watches/buy/this-red-watch` or `example.com/watches/sell/this-blue-watch`. In this case I can keep these pages without a canonical until the same product doesn't have the same page twice, sure?

Comment: Exactly. If each product has a unique URL, and product URL's don't include different category paths, you aren't required to choose one. However, I still recommend implementing canonical URL's sitewide, pointing to themselves. So your watches category would have a canonical pointing to the absolute URL version of example.com/watches. This helps to prevent duplicate content.